Constant error: nextcord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 1000
The first couple of hours works fine, but after that it starts to fail with the following error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nextcord/gateway.py", line 629, in poll_event
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.socket, shard_id=self.shard_id, code=code) from None
nextcord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 1000

I read on different forums, they write that it can be because of the parser
Tried to solve it for a week, even put handlers, still crashes the bot.
Parser accesses Discord API via token, receives new messages from a certain channel, and immediately sends them to another channel.
There is a main bot that receives requests from the user, and there is a parser that accesses the discord API and picks up messages, then they will be forwarded to the main bot.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     # Thread(target=run_main).start()
     print('Thread started.')
     await bot.change_presence(
         status=nextcord.Status.online,
         activity=nextcord.Activity(type=nextcord.ActivityType.watching, name='Active Channels'))
     logger.info(msg='Бот запущен!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
    bot.add_cog(Sharer(bot))

    bot.loop.create_task(main())
    asyncio.run(bot.run(token))


async def main():
    while True:
        tasks = await TasksDAO.find_all()

        for task in tasks:
            messages = await getter.get_messages(task.token, task.id_from)
            new_messages = await getter.filter_new_messages(task.last_message_id, messages)

            if new_messages == 0:  # Если нету last_message_id, обновляем
                messages = await getter.get_messages(task.token, task.id_from)
                await TasksDAO.change_last_message_id(messages[-1]['id'], task.id)  # обновляем id последнего сообщения
            elif new_messages:
                list_messages = [{message['content']: message['id']} for message in messages]
                new_list_messages = [{message['content']: message['id']} for message in new_messages]

                print(list_messages)
                print(new_list_messages)

                await TasksDAO.change_last_message_id(new_messages[-1]['id'], task.id)  # обновляем id последнего сообщения

                bot.dispatch('resending', task.id_to, new_messages, task.token, task.use_link, task.use_embed)```

